# CSS Adjust Parent DIV size if Absolute Child DIV falls outside boundaries

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a parent div that is a specified width and height.  If I have a child div inside that, that is outside the boundaries, is there a way to make the parent div adjust size to fit the child div?

EX:

```
<div style="width:500px; height:500px; position:relative;">
  <div style="width:300px; height:300px; position:absolute; top:250px;">
    Some Content
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in this example the child div would overflow the parent div on the bottom by 50px.  I do not want to use overflow:auto because that just creates scrollbars.  I really want the parent div to adjust and add 50px in height to compensate for the child div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out.

http://jsfiddle.net/jURc9/8/

You want to push the child down 250px from the top of the parent so do no use `top:250px`. Use `margin-top:250px;` and `position:relative;`

Comment: The solution might not work in all cases as intended: if you add paragraph to the beginning, the margin is between the paragraph and the child div instead of the parent div and child div,

Comment: @Prince I updated the fiddle to allow for the width to adjust. Look at the inline css to see what I did.

Comment: @Aleksi You're correct but with the information given, this is an acceptable solution. He could position the `p` absolutely if need be.