# body tag does not display(resizes) controllable

Tags: html, css

I was just testing some basic html and css things out, when I came to a problem I couldn't solve at all.

The Files:

test2.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">
 </head>
 <body class="design1">
  <div id="container">
   <div id="menu" class="box">
     <a href="test2.html#text1" class="box">Abschitt 1</a>
     <a href="test2.html#text2" class="box">Abschitt 2</a>
     <a href="test2.html#text3" class="box">Abschitt 3</a>
   </div>
   <div id="main" class="box">
    <div id="header" class="box">
      <span class="box head">Test2</span>
      <span class="box head">Überschrift</span>
      <span class="box head">10.09.2012</span>
    </div>
    <div id="text" class="box">
     <p id="text1" class="box">
       Lorem ipsum ...
     </p>
     <p id="text2" class="box">
       Lorem ipsum...
     </p>
     <p id="text3" class="box">
       Lorem ipsum...
     </p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="box">
      Von ####
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

test2.css:

```
html, body, div, span {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    border: 0px none;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    outline: 0px none;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.box {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 67, 0.2);
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 67, 1.0);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}

#menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    bottom: 5px;
}

#main {
    position: absolute;
    left: 210px;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
}
```

If I look at the page with Firebug booth, the html and the body element have a size of 0px times 100%(width) and are not visible(The innerHTML part however is displayed). If I delete the last style-specification however they jump back to their normal behaviour and have the size of the complete page (100% times 100%).

test2.css after deleting the last spec:

```
html, body, div, span {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    border: 0px none;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    outline: 0px none;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.box {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 67, 0.2);
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 67, 1.0);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}

#menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    bottom: 5px;
}
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how to avoid it?

Comment: Tried [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qGMD5/)... is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: yes it is. look at the size of the html/body element with Firebug after and before the change. The body element should surround all elements not just the #container/nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you a little bit: 
[CSS Adjust Parent DIV size if Absolute Child DIV falls outside boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188625/css-adjust-parent-div-size-if-absolute-child-div-falls-outside-boundaries)
Though I guess you still have conflicts with the `<p>` tags. I guess `min-height` can help you.

Comment: would you be able to share some code that might help in this particular situation? cheers!